# Delete a structure record from a file

Tags: vb.net

I am working on an application for my ham radio hobby.  The app allows the user to type in a message received via the NTS nets over the air.  I've designed the app so that each message is contained in a structure and the structure is then written via filestream to a file / or appended to the file as the case may be.  I use the serializer to put the data into the file.

The next round of coding will add a feature to remove a message from the file.  This can be needed if the person opts not to deliver the message or takes it by mistake...but that is irrelevant here.  :)

The method I was going to implement would to be loop through the file and read the structured record in one at a time and write it out to a temp file.  When I hit the specific record I want to delete, I'd just skip writing it to the temp file and then continue to the end of the source file.  Then I'd close both files, delete the source and rename the temp file.  It's not hard coding, but I was just curious if there was any pre-built methods in VB.NET that would do this.

Thanks in advance.

Craig

Comment: use a database https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx

Comment: Have you considered using a small database like SQLite instead of a proprietary binary format? It will take much of the pain of this away and provide *much* more functionality later on.

Comment: A database engine will also help keep your data in a consistent state.  It would be possible to write code to do that... but you are just begging for data corruption by handling this logic on your own.

Comment: Assuming what you are talking about is the old `Get` and `Put` methods.  There are **much** better ways.  At the low end is Serializing a `List(of T)` which would allow you to manage the data as a List and simply save it and read it back.  A database is another option.

Comment: Thanks all, I had considered the SQL path and even went as far as trying to install MS SQL Epress on my dev box, but for whatever reason, I could never get that package completely installed.  I'll have to go back to that in the future I think as I'd love to just use SQL for all of the data structures.